# How to determine wether the device is connecting or connected to a Wi-Fi hotspot?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

First I use the method `WifiManager.getWifiState()` to determine wether my device's Wi-Fi is enabled or not. If it's enabled, `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo()` returns a `WifiInfo` object with SSID and other informations I need. But how can I know if the device has already connected to the hotspot with that SSID, or still connecting? Do I have to create a `BroadcastReciever` class?

Answer (score 1):

```
   public  boolean IsWiFiConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    return netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for you:

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null)
        return (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected() && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable());
    else
        return false;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you

```
public static boolean isCheckedNetwork() {

        ConnectivityManager connect = (ConnectivityManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo network = null;
        if (connect != null) {
            network = connect.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        }
        return network == null ? false : network.isConnected();
    }
```